# How to install g++ in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, dependencies, g++

I've tried `sudo apt-get install g++` but I've faced the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Some
packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested
an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution
that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved
out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the
situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  g++: Depends: g++-7
(>= 7.2.0-1~) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct
problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6=2.26-0ubuntu2
sudo apt-get install g++
```